# WinError 2 The system cannot find the file specified Jupyter

Tags: python, anaconda, ibm-cloud, jupyter

I'm working on a project from IBM cloud, and i am trying to import the `watson_machine_learning_client` and jupyter returns the message
`[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`

```
from watson_machine_learning_client import WatsonMachineLearningAPIClient
```

The library should work well, but this is the message it returns:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Here are some screenshots of the message: [Error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8O4E.png) [Error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mi6XU.png)

Comment: Hey and welcome to SO! Are you sure the machine just repeats the line of code that you provide? It doesn't output any error logs?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I attached a screenshot of the error. I am new in this, I have one year programming and I don't know to exaplain it  well. Thanks.